# How to get rid of these triangles on my cheese?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

Here is the node tree, I was following default cube, but his cheeses don't have these grids

[image: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz]

My blend file is here:

[image]

Edit mode:

[image]

Comment: If you have already shaded smooth, this can sometimes be caused by Normal Map or Bump strength being too high.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @AllenSimpson how do I adjust the "normal map" thingy?

Comment: @Chris how do I do that?

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: “How do I adjust..?” Your Bump node: turn the strength down.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard As I said above, I followed default cube's tutorial, and the node setting is exactly the same as his, and his cheese doesn't have grids

Comment: Is it possible that your model has been triangulated at some point in the process?  In any case, the end goal should be a result that pleases you, and not necessarily to follow the tutorial to the letter. :)

Comment: Did you “shade smooth” on the object?

Comment: @Chris [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=wVPmNnMP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wVPmNnMP/)

Comment: @AllenSimpson no, only after making those nodes. And no it doesnt please me, and it doesnt make me happy in any way.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard yes I did shade smoothed them

Comment: Hey,can you send a picture of it in edit mode,that might explain something

Comment: It's only the 'Distance' setting in your Bump map. Either set that lower, (,25?) or, if you want a more exaggerated wobble, you can set the 'Distance' higher, but also give the cheese a level or two of Catmuul-Clark Subdivision. Will answer, later, if no one else does.

Comment: Have you tried turning on auto smooth in the settings of your object?
It's in the object properties tab in the properties panel. With object selected, go to the 'Normals' section and check the "Auto Smooth" box.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati it doesnt change anything, in fact, it looks worse after I turned it on

Comment: I downloaded your .blend and played around a bit. From what I can tell, @AllenSimpson and Robin both had the right of it -- reducing Strength in Bump, or Distance in Bump, both remove these triangular artifacts, for me (although I suspect exactly what Strength setting you should use depends on your light source, and I had changed your Point light to a Sun, as the 2000-strength Point light wasn't lighting any of the objects in the scene when I first opened it).

Comment: Have you tried sellecting all your faces in edit mode, and doing "Normals - Recalculate outside" ?

Comment: @Rajjaiswal https://imgur.com/a/9GO6EGU

Answer (score 9):

I think the underlying triangulation of the mesh being made visible is the result of an extreme 'Distance' value in the *Bump* node.

The *Bump* node has to make an approximation of slopes from heights, by, in some way,  sampling heights of adjacent points in the map, and using the differences. It seems that if the differences are too great, and the slopes too steep, the approximation is not convincing, and exposes the underlying triangle normals, even though they are already interpolated by smooth-shading.

[image]

The illustration shows 'Distance' settings of: 1 (your setting), 0.5, 0.25, and 0.1. The last chunk shows your setting of 1, but with 1 level of Catmull-Clark Subdivision.

(The [code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_bump.osl), (at least the OSL version) points to [this method](http://jbit.net/%7Esparky/sfgrad_bump/mm_sfgrad_bump.pdf) of perturbing normals, given heights. What would make a really proper *explanation* of your artefact, rather than just a fix, would be a more serious mathematician coming along, and describing exactly why the approximation fails. If one comes along, please edit this answer!)

Comment: For rasterizers, I'd suspect derivative discontinuities at edges, because derivatives are always calculated within a single face (within a single "fragment"), so bump can be discontinuous at edges.  For Cycles, I'm not sure, but this is a case where you could easily have terminator artifacts from self-shadowing, and I'd wonder if terminator artifact fixes were made on the expectation of reasonable bump values (here, less than 0.01 distance.)

Comment: Hi @Nathan Yes. I wish I / someone could chase down the `dX()` and `dY()` calls to their implementation.. The cross and dot-products are executed on `N`, the interpolated normal, but you could be right. the derivatives may not cross triangle edges. But that's dealt with in the cited paper, AFAIK.. so.. I dunno...

Comment: so, is there a solution or something to this?

Comment: I can't  think of one, other than reducing 'Distance' in Bump, or upping subdiv, as shown.

Comment: @RobinBetts I have added Subdiv tho

Comment: I've checked i out again.. explored other options.. the only explanation I can find is the same. Height to Normal conversion in the Bump node, not smooth over these very shallow angles, large faces. One thing not suggested in this answer is to put the displacement into the geometry using a modifier? That way you skip the conversion.